# unable to hide the data as expected based on the selection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When user click on Hide Laptop stacked bar radio button, the stacked bar displayed for Laptop(blue color) should be hidden and when clicked on ALL radio button all bars should be displayed. But currently when i click on Hide Laptop stacked bar, the Shipping data is not dispalyed and even the Legend name for shipping is showing wrong when clicked on ALL radio button after Hide Laptop radio button.
Please find the demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/J8I4ZSrIjAj5Wp2gEUEs?p=preview)

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var chart1 = {};
    var variableCol = {
       id: "laptop-id",
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number"
       };
    chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
    chart1.displayed = false;
     var valueSelected;
                $scope.newValue = function(value) {
                    console.log(value);
                    console.log(chart1.data.cols.length);
                    valueSelected = value;
                    if(value == 'few' && chart1.data.cols.length == 5) {
                      alert("Laptop data should not be shown" );
                      chart1.data.cols.pop();  
                    } else {
                      chart1.data.cols.push(variableCol);
                    }

                }
                //if the ALL radio button is selected all the stacked bars should be shown
                //if SDL radio button is selected, show only server,desktop,laptop but onmouse over show the shipping details tooo
    chart1.data = {
      "cols": [{
        id: "month",
        label: "Month",
        type: "string"
      },variableCol,
      {
        id: "desktop-id",
        label: "Desktop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "server-id",
        label: "Server",
        type: "number"
      }, {
          id: "cost-id",
        label: "Shipping",
        type: "number"
      }],
      "rows": [{
        c: [{
          v: "January"
        }, {
          v: 19,
          f: "42 items"
        }, {
          v: 12,
          f: "Ony 12 items"
        }, {
          v: 7,
          f: "7 servers"
        }, {
          v: 4
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
          v: "February"
        }, {
          v: 13
        }, {
          v: 1,
          f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
        }, {
          v: 12
        }, {
          v: 2
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "March"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 11
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }]
    };

    chart1.options = {
      "title": "Sales per month",
      "isStacked": "true",
      focusTarget: 'category',
      "fill": 20,
      "displayExactValues": true,
      colors: ['blue', 'green', 'pink', 'brown'],
      "vAxis": {
        "title": "Sales unit",
        "gridlines": {
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      "hAxis": {
        "title": "Date"
      }
    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1;
  }).value('googleChartApiConfig', {
    version: '1.1',
    optionalSettings: {
      packages: ['bar'],
      language: 'en'
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling [array.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), which removes the last element from the array. The laptop element is at position 1. Here's a snippet of how you would search for the variableCol index, and then splice the array removing that element. That's the safest way to do this since you'll ensure you are finding that particular column.

**So far, these solutions are not solving for the data**

#### Without regard for colors

```
if(value == 'few' && chart1.data.cols.length == 5) {
  //alert("Laptop data should not be shown" );
  var idx = chart1.data.cols.indexOf(variableCol);
  chart1.data.cols.splice(idx, 1);
  console.log("var col at " + idx);
}
```

[Here's a working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/r1HX7GVsd8KFSVAx3MJP?p=preview)

#### Keeping Blue Color for laptop

[This version](https://plnkr.co/edit/hMFkiG8hBrnkrcYPA4sx?p=preview) will keep the laptop being blue (position does change though).

```
 if (value == 'few' && chart1.data.cols.length == 5) {
  //alert("Laptop data should not be shown" );

  var colIdx = chart1.data.cols.indexOf(variableCol);
  chart1.data.cols.splice(colIdx, 1);

  var colorIdx = chart1.options.colors.indexOf("blue");
  chart1.options.colors.splice(colorIdx, 1);

} else {
  chart1.data.cols.push(variableCol);
  chart1.options.colors.push("blue");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, still its not removing the first element(laptop).Even the plnkr you shared is not working as expected.@Brian

Comment: Just opened it again in a clean window and it is working. Perhaps your question is unclear? My sense of working is that changing the radio buttons back and forth repeatedly will add/remove the laptop data from the graph.

Comment: Blue color in the stacked bar represent Laptop data, when clicked on Don't show Data for Laptop button, it is just removing the shipping stacked color and if you notice blue color is mapped to Desktop onmouse over now..i think something got messed up really bad.It is not working. Please compare tooltip on mouse over and the legends when navigating the buttons , u can know the difference..

Comment: I tried fixing the colors, but have to step away from this for a while. The blue does stay, but values are also an issue. The same pattern of finding the proper index has to follow. You'd essentially have to iterate through the month data, and pull out the laptop data, and then push it back. I don't know charts, maybe someone that does knows an easier way to manipulate them, this seems like too much code to do this.

Comment: A quick search gave me this: http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/hide-series/. Why are you trying to re-invent?